# writing C# API as a wrapper of C++ code?

Tags: c#, c++, com, clr

I am Window application developer. I have a C++ library and want to write C# API for this C++ library. I guess I can write COM library by wrapper around this C++ library. But I am not sure if COM library is a language independence. I also heard that .NET framework provide a language independence environment by re-compiling my library to an intermediate code. But I am not quite sure how to do it in .NET.

Since I am quite new in this area, please advice me any resource or technology that I can take a look. Thank you!

Comment: Voted to close - Questions on SO should be geared towards finding a specific solution to a specific problem. Your question is not a good match for that format.

Comment: i suppose i attempted to answer the question already...but it seems like his question is how to consume the C++ library from C#?

Comment: @NadirMuzaffar - That question doesn't have a specific answer without a predefined context. The question in general shows lack of research if nothing else.

Comment: @Unagi, Without the reason why you want to do that it is hard to give you useful info - so voting to close. Search for PInvoke and see if it what you actually asking for http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+pinvoke.

Comment: Hi, just curious, why did you guys want to vote to close? I am just asking if anyone happens to know any specific technology that will allow me to use C++ library from C#. I know COM might be a potential candidate. But I am seeking for alternative solution before I start coding. I don't mind closing my question if this causes any confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM is exactly for language independence. It's main intent is seperation of interface from implementation. You will very likely have to write a COM interface to wrap the C++ library which can then be consumed by C#.

But COM is also a fairly complex as a concept to understand and then properly use. Depending on the size of the library, it might even be faster to rewrite the C++ library as a C# library, then to learn COM and then expose the C++ library through it.

Comment: I just felt that COM can be slow since this library is a real-time News feed. Your previous answer is useful since I can now find a potential solution from the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx. Thanks again.